# Has Steve Rogers ever explicitly endorsed or supported a political party, politician or candidate?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, politics, government

In order to keep them relatable, the political views of superheroes are rarely revealed. However, Captain America is often promoted as an ideal American citizen, and ideal American citizens are generally expected to vote.

While Cap has shown various views, some of which could be considered political, has he ever explicitly endorsed or supported a specific political party, politician or candidate, either real or fictional?

This question applies to the 616 comic universe character only.

Comment: In an alt-universe he was President; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Captain_America

Comment: http://assets1.ignimgs.com/2012/09/18/ultmts2011016int-6-copyjpg-9d912c_800w.jpg

Comment: Do you mean "explicitly" where you wrote "explicably"?  I'd be more interested in the times when he *in*explicably endorsed someone.

Comment: @jwodder - American politics is all inexplicable to me.

Comment: He endorses [punching Adolph in the face](http://comicsalliance.com/files/2015/10/cap-punching-hitler-630x387.jpg)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used to be a regular reader of "Captain America" comic books, but not for many years now. So my information may be out of date . . . but in at least one story in my collection, published in the late 1990s, this subject was explicitly addressed. Just now, I took the time to reread *Captain America #13*, volume 3 (January, 1999).

[image]

As the story begins, Steve Rogers is in an awkward situation. In previous issues of the title, a few things had happened (in between fights with villains and so forth):

1. A congressional candidate named Andrew Bolt, who had filed to challenge an incumbent in the House of Representatives, had asked Captain America for his endorsement (in #4 of this series, according to a footnote). Cap had replied that he *never* gives political endorsements.
2. A bit later on (in #6 of the series), a Skrull had been masquerading as Captain America, and, for some reason, had publicly endorsed Bolt so that everyone thought Cap had decided to make a rare exception because Bolt was such a great candidate!
3. When the truth was brought to light about the Skrull, Bolt was humiliated by the public revelation that he had only been endorsed by a shapechanging alien with a nasty secret agenda, instead of by Captain America. Bolt was afraid that this scandal would badly hurt him at election time, even though he had not done anything wrong.
4. Captain America felt really bad about the whole mess, even though it hadn't been his fault, either. At some point he had checked out Mr. Bolt carefully, and had decided that the man was a squeaky-clean idealist who actually deserved to win that Congressional seat. But Cap still felt he *shouldn't say* exactly that in front of the television cameras, because he didn't want people to think Captain America was trying to formally affiliate himself with one party or faction within the political process. Cap did, however, offer to try to help Mr. Bolt get his campaign back on track . . . in some other way. (But he wasn't sure how he was going to do that.)

All of the above is established (for the benefit of new readers) within the first few pages of #13. During the course of this story, Cap tries some other things which are not directly relevant to your question about him giving endorsements. Then, in the final pages, he reaches a new decision. He decides to spend a lot of time going door-to-door in the relevant district (in Brooklyn, it turns out), in plainclothes, as just plain Steve Rogers, a typical concerned citizen, explaining to one voter at a time why Steve earnestly believes that the country will be better off if Bolt is elected to represent them in Congress.

So the most accurate answer to your question seems to be: "**Captain America** feels he has no business publicly endorsing any candidate or party ticket, no matter what his personal feelings may be. But **Steve Rogers,** in his capacity as just a typical red-blooded American boy who *isn't* a red-white-and-blue Living Legend, feels free to go on record as supporting any candidate he pleases!" (Seems like a reasonable distinction to me.)

Here are some quotes from this issue to show you Steve's philosophy about the right way to handle his Captain America role.

*"Captain American **can't** get involved in **partisan politics**."*

*"In order to earn their **trust,** I have to stand for **all** people. I have to be **Everyman** in a country that's becoming more **diverse** and **fractured** every **day**."*

And on the final page, while explaining himself to his old friend (and ex-girlfriend) Sharon Carter, he says: *"I learned my options the **hard** way. Maybe **Captain America** has limitations . . . but **Steve Rogers'** politics are his **own**."*

(To which Sharon replies: *"I swear, sometimes when you **talk,** I hear the **national anthem**."*)

Of course, the story I just summarized was published at a time when he had a secret identity. The name of "Steve Rogers" had *no special significance* to the typical American citizen of the 616 timeline. I know that later changed -- his identity was revealed to the general public. Although I haven't paid much attention to the "Captain America" comic books in a long time, I would hazard a guess that he still feels he shouldn't go around loudly endorsing candidates if the world will know "Captain America" or "a former Captain America" is the guy making the endorsements.

Comment: Great answer! Does it state which party Bolt belongs to?

Comment: No, I think Mark Waid (the writer) bent over backwards to avoid even using such words as "Democrat" or "Republican" in any context whatsoever in that story. The script made it clear that Steve personally favored Bolt because of his sincerity, rather than just giving the guy the full benefit of the doubt because he was running on a certain party's ticket.